# Tools to benchmark web-services

Tags: web-services, benchmarking

What tools are best for measuring web-services performance?

It would be nice to get report for total transferred data, total POSTs, requests per second, time per request, transfer rate and response time per request.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not quite for web services, but a very simple command line tool is distributed with Apache to benchmark HTTP performance, it is called ApacheBench and can be found in the bin directory as ab.exe

[ApacheBench's documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html)

Comment: Apache Benchmark (ab) is great, simple but powerful command line tool for benchmarking web applications performance. It's main purpose is to benchmark web applications so it is perfect for this task.

Comment: Does this include benchmarking web applications' UI response time?

Comment: No, only requests per second. For profiling the UI, you should use something like [Google PageSpeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/).

Answer (score 3):

I have used [jmeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/) in the past. Check it out.

Comment: I didn't like the first impression of jmeter so witout a doubt I would prefer ab over jmeter.

Comment: @davidhalidor jMeter got special SOAP / Web Service tools.

Answer (score 3):

There is also http://www.soapui.org/ that our QA dept used.

Comment: SoapUI is great for testing web services and making mock web services but I find ab much easier for only benchmarking web services.